Intermittent `NullReferenceException` When Extracting Session ID from WCF Headers in .NET
Question:
I'm developing a .NET Framework application that communicates with a WCF service. Part of my workflow involves logging in to the service and then extracting a session ID from the response headers. The session ID extraction is done using the following method:
static string ExtractSessionIDFromHeaders()
{
    var responseHeaders = OperationContext.Current?.IncomingMessageHeaders;
    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.Count; i++)
    {
        if (responseHeaders[i].Name == "sessionID" && responseHeaders[i].Namespace == "http://ws.polarion.com/session")
        {
            var sessionID = responseHeaders.GetHeader<string>(i);
            return sessionID;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

The Problem:
This method generally works well, but I sometimes encounter a NullReferenceException when calling ExtractSessionIDFromHeaders. Here is the exception message:
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=polarionAPIIntegration
  StackTrace:
   at SBPIIntegrationPlugin.SBPIIntegrationPlugin.ExtractSessionIDFromHeaders() in filepath:/polarionAPIIntegration\polarionAPIIntegration\PolarionIntegration.cs:line 1001

What I've Tried:

I have verified that the OperationContext.Current is not null before accessing IncomingMessageHeaders.
The exception does not occur consistently; it works most of the time but fails intermittently.
I have added logging to see the state of the OperationContext and headers at runtime, but the issue is sporadic.

Questions:

Why might OperationContext.Current?.IncomingMessageHeaders be null or inaccessible intermittently?
What are the best practices for reliably extracting headers from a WCF service response in such cases?
Could this issue be related to threading, timing, or some other aspect of WCF that I'm overlooking?

Additional Context:

The method is called within an OperationContextScope.

I’m using BasicHttpBinding with the following settings:
  var bindings = new BasicHttpBinding
  {
      OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
      CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
      SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
      ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
      MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000000,
      MaxBufferSize = 1000000000
  };



Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Are you involved in multithreading or asynchronous operations? If your code is running in multiple threads and you try to access OperationContext.Current, it may return null in one thread because OperationContext is bound to the thread that created it.
During an asynchronous call, OperationContext.Current may not be available in all threads, as it only applies to threads related to WCF operations. If you access it in an asynchronous method, it can result in null.
